# Can't send push messages using GCM

Tags: android, json, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM in my android app. I have 1461 users registered. I am using JSON method to send messages to server. When I try to send a push message I get an error like

> "Number of messages on bulk (1461) exceeds maximum allowed (1000)"

Is it because GCM has a limitation for number of messages? Or is it a problem with JSON?

Comment: It has a limit of 1000 devices per multicast message. If you're sending JSON data it defaults to multicast. I'd guess that is the limit you're hitting.

Comment: @Rama: I saw this on google groups.But is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 6):

@Basim Sherif you can only send 1000 user in one request, it is limitation of GCM for other user you have to send second request