# Number of messages on bulk exceeds maximum allowed... How to solve this issue do i need to increase my limit and if yes then how can I?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

[image: number of messages in bulk exceeds(1600) the maximum allowed limit(1000)]

.... Please tell possible solutions. Do i need to increase bulk messages maximum limit and if yes then how can i increase maximum allowed limit ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't send push messages using GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629670/cant-send-push-messages-using-gcm)

Answer (score 5):

You should split your GCM request into multiple requests, each containing at most 1000 registration IDs.

There is no way to send a single message to over 1000 registration IDs.